# Computing an Integral with a limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

My question is-

Compute: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}\left(x^2+\frac{1}{n}\sin(e^{\cos x})\right)~dx$

I'm probably thinking too hard about this but as $1/n$, when tending to infinity, is $0$ is the answer to this simply just $\int_{0}^{1}x^2~dx$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Split the integral into a sum, and factor the $1/n$ outside the second integral.  Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right, since $n$ doesn't affect the integral:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}(x^2+\frac{1}{n}\sin(e^{\cos(x)}))dx$$

So you can divide it as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}x^2dx+\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{n}\sin(e^{\cos x})dx$$

Since $1/n$ doesn't affect the integral, and can be quit as a constant, make this:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}x^2dx+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{1}\sin(e^{\cos x})dx$$

Now, you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}x^2dx$ isn't affected by $n$, so you have:

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx+ 0 \int_{0}^{1}\sin(e^{\cos(x)})dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx=\frac{x^3}{3} \text{ from } 0 \text{ to } 1$$

That is

$$\frac{1^3}{3}-\frac{0^3}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$$